# How to use the fragment's getActivity() method to pass a context?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on an android app, and it suddenly gave me these errors

Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead

and

This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)

This is the code:

```
public AFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, Context context)
{
    AFragment fragment = new AFragment(context);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public AFragment(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
}
```

How to use the fragment's getActivity() method to pass a context ( mContext = context )?

Comment: Get rid of the `mContext` field, and just use `getActivity()` anywhere you need a `Context` in the `Fragment` class. Don't try to pass one in a constructor.

Comment: You don't need to pass a context to a fragment… just do `file -> new project` and create a project with a default activity/fragment and see what google did. It's very simple and will teach you the "right way". ;) Don't use constructors other than a default empty constructor in fragments, ever. (or you will regret it in the future).

Answer (score 2):

You should never need to pass a Context to a Fragment.

You can remove from `newInstance` parameters

Wherever you use that Context field in the Fragment, you replace it with getActivity().

If you really want to use a field, you must assign it in `onAttach` and remember to unassign it when the Fragment is stopped or detached from any Activity

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are the child's or part of the activity. So whenever you want context in fragment you can use getActivity() as context.

Comment: that's not an option if he tried to re-use that fragment in more than 1 activity.